# PrimeFaces centering searchbar on menubar

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Been trying to center the search field on the menubar. It either sticks to the far left or far right, I have used float left and right using css as follows to no avail:

```css
body .ui-menu.ui-menubar>.ui-menu-list>.ui-menuitem.ui-menubar-options {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
body .ui-menu.ui-menubar>.ui-menu-list>.ui-menuitem.ui-menubar-options > button {
  float: right !important;
}
body .ui-menu.ui-menubar>.ui-menu-list>.ui-menuitem.ui-menubar-options > input {
  float: none !important;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

The below image is the one I want to create, where I shift the search bar from right to the right highlighted section. Any suggestions please?
[image: Searchbar location]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the MenuBar was not designed to have centered items so you will have to "hack" it.

You have to remove `float:right` on the menubar and then adding padding from the left until its centered where you want it.

```css
body .ui-menu.ui-menubar>.ui-menu-list>.ui-menuitem.ui-menubar-options {
   float:none;
   margin-left: 5rem;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Using display flex would have been my weapon of choice here. Did not answer as (like you mentioned) it's not designed that way. It might only make sense with a small amount of menu items and a fairly large screen.